# Replacing If Else Chains with Switch: Unreachable after return

Tags: javascript

```
function chainToSwitch(val) {
  var answer = "";
  // Only change code below this line
  switch (val) {
    case "bob":
      answer = "Marley";
      break;
    case 42: 
      answer = "The answer";
      break;
    case 1:
      answer = "There is no #1";
      break;
    case 99:
      answer = "Missed me by this much!";
      break;
    case 7:
      answer = "Ate Nine";
      break;
    default: 
      answer = "not correct";
  }
}

  // Only change code above this line  
  return answer; 


// Change this value to test
chainToSwitch(7);
```

I still don't understand why it isn't reachable. I'm doing FreeCodeCamp courses and I am stuck on this one. I've even went into the source code for the answer and it still will not work for me.

Comment: put the `return` statement inside the function just below the `switch` scope

Comment: Look at the format....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `return` statement inside of the function.

```js
function chainToSwitch(val) {
  var answer = "";
  // Only change code below this line
  switch (val) {
    case "bob":
      answer = "Marley";
      break;
    case 42: 
      answer = "The answer";
      break;
    case 1:
      answer = "There is no #1";
      break;
    case 99:
      answer = "Missed me by this much!";
      break;
    case 7:
      answer = "Ate Nine";
      break;
    default: 
      answer = "not correct";
  }
  return answer; 
}

console.log(chainToSwitch(7));
```